# Using a shell script to write the names of all executables in a folder, with formatting, to a text file?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have about 200 C files that I need to format to a text file like so:

```
sem_post_stress.c
dup_fdopendir.c
shm_open.c and 198 others...
```

after making the files, the binaries are stored in `./aarch64/le/` along with `.o` and `.dep`.

I need to create a text file used at startup to make my image with the  ~200 binaries, formatted like so, one line per binary:

```
/tmp/sem_post_stress = /home/.../.../.../.../aarch64/le/sem_post_stress

/tmp/dup_fdopendir = /home/.../.../.../.../aarch64/le/dup_fdopendir

/tmp/shm_open = /home/.../.../.../.../aarch64/le/shm_open
```

From this link: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/bash-scripting-loops

I know how to rename all files like: `for i in $(ls *.); do`
but not how to add a prefix for my qemu environment `"/tmp/"` or the rest, `=` and `absolute path`.

I'm new to bash and never use it so I apologize if this is trivial, I have looked everywhere.
Any hints or code is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You only need to create the text file (with the lines like so: `/tmp/some` = `/home/..../aarch64/le/some`), don't you? Or do you want to rename the files too?

Comment: Only need to create the text file, going to leave the binary names as is

Comment: Looping over the output of `ls` is a **terrible** idea. With Bash, consider: `shopt -s nullglob; for f in *; do <something>; done`. Look [here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) to learn why.

Comment: @Cbhihe, very true. And sad to see RedHat documentation laden with so many coding bad practice most of which wouldn't even pass the shellcheck test.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
(for file (aarch64/le/*(N*)) print -r /tmp/$file:t = $file:P) > file.out
```

Where:

- `aarch64/le/*(N*)` expands to the list of non-hidden executable regular files in `aarch64/le`, `(N*)` being [glob qualifiers](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers), `N`ullglob for the list to expand to nothing if there's no match, `*` to select executable files (mnemonic: same as the prefix `ls -F` uses for executable files).
- `$var:t` takes the `t`ail of a path (its basename).
- `$var:P` takes the `real`P`ath` of a path (its absolute, canonical, symlink free path as the `realpath()` standard function or `realpath` command does).

With GNU `find` and any shell (even bash, the GNU shell):

```
LC_ALL=C find "$PWD/aarch64/le/" -maxdepth 1 ! -name '.*' -executable -type f \
  -printf '/tmp/%f = %p\n' > file.out
```

Beware contrary to the zsh approach, that gives an unsorted list.

POSIXly with standard `sh` and utilities:

```
for file in aarch64/le/*; do
  if [ -x "$file" ] && [ -f "$file" ] && [ ! -L "$file" ]; then
    printf '%s\n' "/tmp/${file##*/} = $PWD/$file"
  fi
done > file.out
```

(also works in zsh and bash though note that in zsh (or bash if the `failglob` option is set), if there's no non-hidden file in `aarch64/le/`, you'll get an error).